# Windows 10 - proxy server restricting my internet access

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, proxy

I have a problem with my windows 10 machine - since the last update *some* of my apps show various errors or cannot connect to internet, while others, like jetbrains products, tell me that there are issues with the proxy server and ask me to enter a login & password.

But I haven't created any proxy server at all, I only updated windows.

**How do I disable all proxy servers in windows, or what can I do to make my apps work again?**

This problem also prevents me from using any VPN as they display errors like I have no internet connection, but the weird thing is that many online games still work.

**Firefox lets me browse the internet freely, but when I tried to update it, it told me that it cannot connect to the internet...**

I have confirmed that this isn't an issue with my ISP or router, as accessing the internet and doing various things on other PCs in my home still works perfectly fine on linux / windows 7 / not updated windows 10 machines.

[image: Error with proxy in jetbrains CLION]
[image: Issue with teamviewer - I have internet connection and reply to you - TV thinks I don't have internet]
[image: Same with proton vpn]

even malwarebytes online installer failed to install - it said that it cannot access server, and I should check my internet connection.

Comment: Have you checked for malware that might be redirecting things?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I scanned pc with malwarebytes & bitdefender, they found some adware, restarted pc and problem still persists

Comment: Find and download the latest drivers for your mainboard and your network controller. Uninstall the current network controller drivers, restart and then install the new ones. Install the new mainboard drivers too. Also, if there are any error codes provided by the apps failing to connect, could you include those in the question?

Comment: Re: malware, a scan from the Windows HDD may not be able to remove all (and some really nasty pieces can't effectively be removed at all). Try a scan from rescue media.

Comment: added screenshots, all of those apps worked perfectly fine before update